# SQL Server Query Join taking very long when adding an additional column in the join

Tags: sql, performance, sql-server-2012, execution-time, database-tuning

I'm running a basic query on a table with a unique ID in each table, which is a non-clustered index in each.  One table has 8 million rows, and the other has 800,000 rows.

When I run the following, it returns 24,000 rows in less than a second:

```
select     
    a.[ID]      
    ,b.[ID]    
from     
    dbo.tbl_1 a    
join     
    dbo.tbl_2 b    
on 
    a.unique_id = b.unique_id
```

However, when I add an additional column in the join which will significantly reduce the recordset, this takes about 8 minutes

```
select     
    a.[ID]      
    ,b.[ID]    
from     
    dbo.tbl_1 a    
join     
    dbo.tbl_2 b    
on 
    a.unique_id = b.unique_id 
    AND a.code_letter = b.code_letter
```

The "code_letter" column is just one letter, and is set to varchar(1).  I'm scratching my head trying to understand why this is hanging.  The issue is that I've run a dynamic sql insert query with 20,000 permutations of joins, and it's taking way too long.

**Edit**
After trying this many ways, I realized that a simple `select *` seems to work very efficiently, while selecting specific columns is the culprit.  Here is the execution plan when I `select *`:

[image: select all query]

Here is the execution plan when I select specific columns:

[image: select specific columns]

Again, my join is exactly the same, but the column selections are different.

Comment: Have you tried to create indexes on code_letter columns?

Comment: I have, and that did not help for some reason.....but even if it did, it would be an annoying situation where I'd have to create an index for each iteration and drop it which could also be time consuming.

Comment: I'm wondering if it has something to do with cache-ing of the execution plan or something like that.  It seems set off by the dynamic SQL that keeps runnign insert queries over and over with different columns in the join?

Comment: For performance questions, please show query plan from `EXPLAIN`. Is the 8 minutes the result of that single query by itself or your *dynamic sql insert query* process? if latter, show fuller TSQL code.

Comment: It's from the single query.  This is in t-sql so I can't use explain.  I bring up the dynamic part in case there's some reason to believe that would cause an unexpected issues.

Comment: I created an exact index on the columns in the join and that didn't help.  Also, the execution plan was the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP said, he didn't get the expected results, and based on his observations, I'll provide a different solution.

<strike>What I would do is, execute the following and get data to a temp table</strike>

```
select     
    a.[ID] as aID      
    ,b.[ID] as bID
    ,a.code_letter as aCode_letter  
    ,b.code_letter as bCode_letter
into #t
from     
    dbo.tbl_1 a    
join     
    dbo.tbl_2 b    
on 
    a.unique_id = b.unique_id
```

and then exec the following

```
Select aID, bID from #t Where aCode_letter = bCode_letter
```

```
select DISTINCT a.*    
into #ta
from     
    dbo.tbl_1 a    
join     
    dbo.tbl_2 b    
on 
    a.unique_id = b.unique_id 

select DISTINCT b.*    
into #tb
from     
    dbo.tbl_1 a    
join     
    dbo.tbl_2 b    
on 
    a.unique_id = b.unique_id
```

And exec

```
Select a.ID, b.ID 
from #ta a
Inner Join #tb b 
on a.unique_id = b.unique_id and a.Code_letter = b.Code_letter
```

Comment: I tried that and it was unfortunately time consuming.  Here's the latest I've learned:  When I run: ```Select * ``` that seems to return results in seconds, whereas when I choose specific columns it spins for minutes.  I've never seen that before, and it's rather unexpected behavior.

Comment: Then why do't you do it like that. ie. Select * and then do the 2nd part separately?
Or get a.* separately and b.* in to another temp tbl and then join those 2

Comment: The issue there is just I'd have to do a lot of renaming of columns.  I am adding the execution plan differences to the original issue if that helps to determine why it's executing so differently.

Comment: please try my new suggestion

Comment: That does work, although it seems like a workaround that should be avoidable.  Thank you!

Comment: I have only a limited info. If it is my DB, I would have tried different options. Unfortunately I have to base only on what you have provided here.

Comment: I added "DISTINCT" to the select since otherwise you can run into a cartesian join situation.

Comment: @sqlnewbie1979,
As I told you, I do not have a way to experiment and test. i was under the assumption that the data you will get are unique from each table, as you were taking all records. If it is not the case, yes, better to have distinct. How is the performance after adding DISTINCT?

Comment: Yes, much better and your solution was extremely helpful.

Comment: For future reference, what else would be helpful to provide?

Comment: For this type of a situation it is hard to provide much. If it is something where i can experiment for myself, i would have tried other options as to why all columns are faster than few columns, why need to have distinct and so on. Its hard to tell how i would do.